# Syntax highlighting in HAML's markdown filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax-highlighting, haml, markdown

I'm using HAML's markdown filter, like this:

```
:markdown
  This is markdown text, yay!
```

but I want to do syntax highlighting for code inside that text, something like:

```
:markdown
  This is markdown text, yay!
  <code lang="ruby">
    def hello(world)
      puts "Hello #{world}"
    end
  </code>
```

Any ideas how to do it? I know how to use CodeRay, but I don't see how to grab ahold of that text.

Comment: Syntax highlighting in what text editor/IDE?

Comment: @Phrogz In the produced HTML.

Comment: @JPablo I'm sorry, I still don't understand your question then. Are you asking what HTML markup and JS library you should use to get automatic syntax coloring in the web browser? If so, this is unrelated to Haml, Markdown, or Rails. Neither Haml nor Markdown automagically produce HTML or CSS that yields syntax highlighting for any particular language.

Comment: What I'm saying is that I have markdown inside haml and I want to post or pre process that code to be syntax highlighted (if nothing more automatic exists). I was hoping that maybe one of the markdown libraries like maruku could do it when generating the HTML, but apparently there's nothing. An alternative as posted by Michael using JavaScript could work.

Comment: Since this post is old I won't bother with an answer but these folks are right about needing more to get markdown to render syntax highlighting. But since time has gone by there are hosts of tools you may use. One that I am working with these days is https://github.com/grosser/ultraviolet but there is a newer version https://github.com/chaffeqa/uv and examples for it's use are in https://github.com/wbzyl/rack-codehighlighter and another https://github.com/glenngillen/rack-syntax-highlighter  and another https://github.com/unindented/rack-highlighter and how to invoke it in the config.ru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Markdown does support code blocks out of the box, but does not support syntax highlighting.

see http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#markdown-filter for what markdown libraries haml looks for to parse your markdown.

If you want to pass your code to a filter that makes it highlighted you can write your own filter extension to haml.  It is actually quite easy.

http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Haml/Filters/Base.html

If I were you though, I would just put the code in as a block and use a javascript library like GeSHi to highlight the code.  http://qbnz.com/highlighter/index.php

So you can do something like:

```
  %pre.ruby 
    puts "this is now syntax highlighted"
```

And if you have geshi included, it now highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

http://railscasts.com/episodes/272-markdown-with-redcarpet  uses albino, nokogiri and pygments